# Does the Glance App Widget support CountDownTimer

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-widget, glance-appwidget, glance

[image]

**Is any support to add widget like this in the Android Glance AppWidget?**

Comment: `Is any support to add widget like this in the Android Glance AppWidget?` what part of it ? Glance lets you make widgets with compose, it doesn't just feature widgets out of the box, right ? so, what are you looking for here specifically ?